# How to sort numbers(can be super big) in string in java most efficiently

Tags: java, string, algorithm, integer

Given a String like "4, 100, -2147483647, 1" I want to sort it like "-2147483647, 1, 4, 100". So far I have tried splitting the String, and run parseInt on the Strings produced by splitting. However, since parseInt cannot handle numbers out of scope, it throws me NumberFormatException. What would be the most efficient way of handling this? (time, precision...) Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529045/how-do-i-sort-strings-that-contain-numbers-in-java

Comment: How big is super big? Like `long` big or `BigInteger` big?

Comment: Taken literally, you want as output a `String` listing the numbers in order of increasing numerical value. How will the numbers be separated in the input? (When seeking support handling a run time error by all means _cut&paste the error message_ (adjusting locale to _en_ if need be).)

Comment: @Vasan [>= 11](https://www.xkcd.com/670/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting it to an `int` will limit your input. If you leave the numbers as strings, then you could have upwards of 2 billion digits.

After that, you can create an algorithm to compare the sizes of the numbers. If they are the same size, go through each number from left to right and find which is the largest. Otherwise, the number with fewer digits is smaller.

Also check for negatives, since you seem to want that checked also.

Answer (score 2):

None of the numbers you provided in your example are out of scope for an integer.  The following program would parse your provided string and sort it appropriately...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "4, 100, -2147483647, 1";

    String[] strArray = s.split(", ");

    ArrayList intList = new ArrayList();

    for(int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
        intList.add(Integer.parseInt(strArray[i]));
    }

    Collections.sort(intList);

    System.out.println(intList);
}
```

The output from this program would be as follows....

```
[-2147483647, 1, 4, 100]
```

If you have a number larger than 2,147,483,647 or smaller than -2,147,483,648 then you can use a long or BigInteger like John Kugelman suggested.

Answer (score 1):

First convert each number to String and store them in a string array
Here unsorted is the reference to the unsorted array. Here i have just used a lamda expression to use as a comparator (java8) if you want to try to run for java 7, just use a Comparator with the given conditions and pass it along

```
    Arrays.sort(unsorted, (left, right) -> {
        if (left.length() != right.length()) {
            return left.length() - right.length();
        } else {
            return left.compareTo(right);
        }
    });
    return unsorted;
```

Comment: This ignores negative numbers, featured in the example from the question.

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers don't fit in `int`s, try `long`s. As in, `parseLong`.

It's unlikely, but if you need something even bigger than that, use [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html). It can handle anything you throw at it.

Comment: That may still overflow. `BigInteger` would not.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "4, 100, -2147483647, 1";

    String[] strArray = s.split(", ");

    List<BigDecimal> intList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String element : strArray) {
        intList.add(new BigDecimal(element));
    }

    Collections.sort(intList);

    System.out.println(intList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [@SumitKumarSaha](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49835116/2652368) answer in **Kotlin**:

```
list.sortWith { left, right ->
    if (left.length != right.length)
        left.length - right.length
    else
        left.compareTo(right);
}
```